# How to display object properties within an object in Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an object called USAFacts with properties such as StateName and objects such as State-Bird with properties about the state bird.

In JSON a record of USAFacts would look like this:

```
{"StateName": PA, "State-Bird": [ { "Name": Ruffed grouse, "YearDesignated": 1931, "ScientificName": "Bonasa umbellus"}]}
```

I can acesss the StateName property in Angular2 using

```
{{ USAFacts?.StateName }}
```

How can I access the name of the state bird? I've tried to do it like this:

```
{{USAFacts?.State-Bird.Name }}
```

but am getting an error in chrome saying cannot read property of undefined 'Name'

Comment: Use bracket notation? `{{USAFacts['State-Bird'][0].Name }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use special characters in a property name.

In your **JSON** replace `State-Bird` with `StateBird`

And to access the `Name` property you need to first access the array `StateBird`.

```
{{USAFacts?.StateBird[0].Name}}
```

But, if you want to use special characters, you can use bracket notation to access that property without changing it's name

```
{{USAFacts?["State-Bird"][0].Name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{USAFacts?.State-Bird[0].Name }}
```

That is array of object/s